# Restoring App Data from Backup

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, backup, restore

How can I restore one app’s data from an encrypted iTunes backup (iOS 11.3.1) to the same app on iOS 11.4? I deleted the Readdle Documents app by mistake and I had some files in it I would like back. I would prefer free or open source tools if possible. I am using Windows 10.

(I don’t believe this is possible in iTunes. <s>I tried iMacTools’ iBackup Viewer, and it only extracted what seemed to be placeholders for my files.</s> (See answer below.))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the files stored in *Readdle Documents* are not stored in the normal location where apps store their *Documents and Data*. (This may be because *Readdle Documents* lists itself as a *Cloud Storage Provider*.) Using the *Tree View* of the *Raw Files* section of *iBackup Viewer*, I was able to export the files in the *AppDomainGroup-group.com.readdle.documents/File Provider Storage* folder and reupload the files into *Readdle Documents* through its WebDAV feature.

I downloaded iBackup Viewer from https://www.imactools.com/iphonebackupviewer/.